How to run ctags on vim start?
I am running in my vim :let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='"/opt/homebrew/bin/ctags"' so that ctags can work properly. Is there a way to configure vim to run it automatically so I don't have to do each time I launch vim?

Tlist_Ctags_Cmd is a plugin-specific "option" that is totally meaningless to Vim. Read your plugin's documentation and use its issue tracker. As for running command "automatically", see :help autocommand.

@Jim Ever heard about .vimrc?

@phd: Yes. But how can I specify that :let in the .vimrc?

@Jim Any command you can run in the vim command line can be written in vim script files. Omit : because code in vim script files are exactly that — Ex-commands. Though if you use : in the script files they wouldn't hurt because you can use :: in the command line.

@phd: I followed what you said and it worked. Please if you want add it as an answer and I'll accept it

Simply add
let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='"/opt/homebrew/bin/ctags"'

to your ~/.vimrc.
